# Way to print Twitter handle in json via Python with requests module?

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, python-requests

I'm making a Twitter bot to search Twitter for specific keywords and phrases from recent Tweets. I've been using [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/searching-for-tweets-with-python-f659144b225f) document as a guide, which uses the Python requests module.

```
import requests
import json

BEARER_TOKEN = "XYZ"

#define search twitter function
def search_twitter(query, tweet_fields, bearer_token = BEARER_TOKEN):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&{}".format(
        query, tweet_fields
    )
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.status_code)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()

#search term
query = "new music"
#twitter fields to be returned by api call
tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=text,author_id,created_at"

#twitter api call
json_response = search_twitter(query=query, tweet_fields=tweet_fields, bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
#pretty printing
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Everything works fine when I run it in the terminal, but I can't seem to find a way to print each Tweet's associated Twitter handle. I can't find the specific documentation/syntax.

I know I have to edit this line of code to include the Twitter handle:

```
tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=text,author_id,created_at"
```

Simply put, I also want to print the actual Twitter handle associated with these Tweets. Any and all information would be deeply appreciated.

---

New code including expansions:

```
import requests
import json
#its bad practice to place your bearer token directly into the script (this is just done for illustration purposes)
BEARER_TOKEN = "XYZ"
#define search twitter function
def search_twitter(query, tweet_fields, expansions, bearer_token = BEARER_TOKEN):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&{}".format(
        query, tweet_fields, expansions
    )
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.status_code)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()

#search term
query = "new music"
#twitter fields to be returned by api call
# twitter fields to be returned by api call
tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=author_id,created_at"
expansions = "expansions=author_id"

# twitter api call
json_response = search_twitter(query=query, tweet_fields=tweet_fields, expansions=expansions, bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
#pretty printing
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: I think if you want the twitter handle you will need to use the `author_id` to make a query against the [user endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference).

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, thanks for the response. Pardon my ignorance, but how would I integrate this into my Python code? This is my first project of the sort and working with APIs so I have a ton I still need to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [expansions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/expansions) in the v2 Twitter API to get back the associated user object in the same call.

The simplest way to illustrate this is with a single Tweet. For example, using curl:

```sh
$ curl 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1212092628029698048?tweet.fields=author_id,created_at&expansions=author_id' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'
```

This requests a Tweet with the default fields (`text` and `id` are always included so you do not specifically have to request them) as well as the `author_id` and `created_at` values, and then asks for the `author_id` aka User object to be expanded in the response as well:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1212092628029698048",
    "author_id": "2244994945",
    "created_at": "2019-12-31T19:26:16.000Z",
    "text": "We believe the best future version of our API will come from building it with YOU. Here’s to another great year with everyone who builds on the Twitter platform. We can’t wait to continue working with you in the new year. <short url removed for SO posting>"
  },
  "includes": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "2244994945",
        "name": "Twitter Dev",
        "username": "TwitterDev"
      }
    ]
  }
```

You will find the handle of the Twitter user in the `includes.users.username` field.

So, in your code, you could do this:

```py
# twitter fields to be returned by api call
tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=author_id,created_at"
expansions = "expansions=author_id"

# twitter api call
json_response = search_twitter(query=query, tweet_fields=tweet_fields, expansions=expansions, bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
```

(also add `expansions` to the `search_twitter` function as an input, and for the `url` string formatting)

For an array / list of Tweets that you might get returned from a search call, note that you might need to do a lookup into the `includes`, as you will get `data` (Tweet objects) and then `includes` (User objects + any other expansions you might request), and if the same user is represented more than once in the list of Tweets, it will only be returned once in the `includes` - in this case, match up the `author_id` values to find the `username` for the associated Tweet.

Comment: (if this was a useful answer please mark it as accurate, thank you)

Comment: This is a great response! I'm currently testing your code. It's still returning the same information in my array sans user/Twitter handle. I've gone ahead and edited my original post to include my new code with your recommendations. I believe I might need to add something with the "includes" to get it to show the Twitter handle in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: `/recent?query={}&{}"` that should now be `/recent?query={}&{}&{}"` as you are inserting three values, not two.